# Web font icon not displaying on html kendo grid

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, developer-tools

I have an html kendo grid that does not show the filter icon image. However, it still filters. I've been using the chrome developer tools and when pages uploads it always generates span class="k-icon k-filer". I changed it to span class="k-icon k-i-filer" and filter image displays. It also show that it is being overwritten in the developer tools. I'm not sure how to implement this in my code for it to work.

```
     columns.Bound(p => p.CurrentApplicationStatusText)
          .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("applicationStatusFilter"))
          .Title("Application Status")
          .Width(160);columns.Bound(p => p.StudentDOB)
          .Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
          .Title("DOB")
          .Width(100);

     .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height: 579px; width: 110%"})
  .Scrollable()
  .Sortable()
  .Filterable(filterable => filterable
      .Extra(false)
      .Operators(operators => operators
          .ForString(str => str.Clear()
              .Contains("Contains")
              .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
              .StartsWith("Starts with")
              .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
```

[image: Filter Icon Missing]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure those images are under ***Bootstrap*** folder if you use Bootstrap theme.

Here is the folder structure.

[image]

Expanded view

[image]

*If you want to bundle them,  please see [my sample project](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs#L20) at GitHub.*

Comment: I don't have font-awesome.css or font-awesome.min.css anywhere. What are those files for, Win?

Comment: Please ignore them if you do not use font awesome.

Comment: I have them bundle and all the files seem to exist. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: If you bundle Kendo css files, you will need to follow the original path. For example, if Kendo css file is `~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css`, the bundle should be `~/Content/kendo/css`. Look at [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs#L30) code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css block like this:

```
.k-filter:before {
    content: "\e129";
}
```